# Trying to obtain information from a specific line, given a string input, to another specific line, for an intended output

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to build a function that takes the input from the user, searches for that input in a string (from a text file), and then reads that string from that line to an intended "end" line. Below is the attached code snippet that does not include an answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string dataFile, dataSFile, accNum, Name, Number, SS, Address, Bal, endV;
    dataFile = "accounts.txt";
    ifstream fin1(dataFile);
    if(!fin1.is_open()){
        cout << "\033[91mError Gathering Account Information.\nPlease contact your IT Administrator.\n \n";
        return 0;
    }
    getline(fin1, dataSFile, '\0');
    ofstream fout1(dataFile, std::ios_base::app);
    cout << "Please enter the acc #" << endl;
    getline(cin, accNum);
    if(dataSFile.find(accNum) != std::string::npos){
    fin1 >> Name >> "\0" >> Number >> "\0" >> SS >> "\0" >> Address >> "\0" >> Bal >> "\0" >> endV;
    cout << "[" << accNum << "]" << endl;
    cout << Name << endl;
    cout << Number << endl;
    cout << SS << endl;
    cout << Address << endl;
    cout << Bal << end;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in "accounts.txt", the following items exist.

```
[10111]
Gerald Gray
800-111-1111
222-22-2222
19 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00000
$0
[end]

[10222]
James Murray
800-222-2222
333-33-3333
20 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00001
$500
[end]
```

I would like to use `file.find() != std::string:npos` to find the string in the text, determine the location, and select the lines following down until it reaches `[end]`.

### EX:

Please enter the acc #
10111

[10111]
Gerald Gray
800-111-1111
222-22-2222
19 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00000
0

`end of output`

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you!

I have only tried using getline and fin, as I'm lacking any other way to do so.

`

## UPDATE

I have found the method I am searching for, but I am unable to understand why str.find() removes some characters when it is located. The following code is what I am using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
 
 using namespace std;
std::string trail = "[10111] Gerald Gray 800-111-1111 222-22-2222 19 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00000 $500000 [end] [10222] James Murray 800-222-2222 333-33-3333 20 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00001 $500 [end]";
int main(){
    string y;
    cin >> y;
    size_t pos1 = trail.find("[" + y + "]");
    size_t pos2 = trail.find("[end]");
    string strinS = trail.substr (pos1, pos2);
    cout << strinS << endl;
}
```

for ease, I have moved the text file into the actual code while running these tests. What I have found is that, instead of outputting the number I need, it outputs *some* of it.

**--Input--**

10222

**--Expected Output--**

James Murray 800-222-2222 333-33-3333 20 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00001 $500

**--Direct Output--**

James Murray 800-222-2222 333-33-3333 20 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00001 $500 [e

How would I set an end point for substr? It feels almost redundant to have a start point but no end point variable. All help is appreciated!

Comment: If you planned to do many searches on the file content, I would parse the whole file into a map of registers, indexed by the account number, and then just query the map for a given account number when needed.

Comment: Side note: Check the stream state after every IO transaction so you can be sure it worked. Error conditions that you don't check for and handle sooner or later waste debugging time.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using an input string stream instead of a file stream:

- There is an `account` struct, and an `accounts` unordered map.
  Account objects can be printed (e.g. with `std::cout << account`).
- The main code just calls `parse`, passing an input stream, an receiving an `accounts` map.
- The `parse` function keeps reading lines from the input stream.
  Whenever it finds a line that matches an account number, it tries to read the rest of the account fields from the next lines.
  If it failed to do so (because there are no more lines to be read, or because some of the lines read don't match an expected pattern), it continues looping or exits the loop.
  Otherwise, it adds a new account to the map.
- The account ID and the balance are matched using regular expressions.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/x6GrfocWc)

```cpp
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <unordered_map>

struct account {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    std::string phone_no;
    std::string ss;
    std::string address;
    int balance;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const account& a) {
        fmt::print(os,
            "id: {}, name: '{}', phone_no: '{}', ss: '{}', address: '{}', balance: {}",
            a.id, a.name, a.phone_no, a.ss, a.address, a.balance);
        return os;
    }
};

using accounts = std::unordered_map<int, account>;

accounts parse(std::istringstream& iss) {
    accounts ret{};
    for (std::string id_line{}; std::getline(iss, id_line);) {
        account acc{};
        std::regex id_pattern{"\\[([[:digit:]]+)\\]"};
        std::regex balance_pattern{"\\$([[:digit:]]+)"};
        std::string end_pattern{"[end]"};
        std::smatch id_matches{};
        std::smatch balance_matches{};
        std::string balance_line{};
        std::string end_line{};

        if (std::regex_match(id_line, id_matches, id_pattern) and
            std::getline(iss, acc.name) and
            std::getline(iss, acc.phone_no) and
            std::getline(iss, acc.ss) and
            std::getline(iss, acc.address) and
            std::getline(iss, balance_line) and
            std::regex_match(balance_line, balance_matches, balance_pattern) and
            std::getline(iss, end_line) and
            end_line == end_pattern) {

            acc.id = std::stoi(id_matches[1]);
            acc.balance = std::stoi(balance_matches[1]);
            ret.insert({acc.id, acc});
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{
        "[10111]\n"
        "Gerald Gray\n"
        "800-111-1111\n"
        "222-22-2222\n"
        "19 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00000\n"
        "$0\n"
        "[end]\n"
        "\n"
        "[10222]\n"
        "James Murray\n"
        "800-222-2222\n"
        "333-33-3333\n"
        "20 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00001\n"
        "$500\n"
        "[end]\n"
    };
    auto accs{parse(iss)};
    for (const auto& [key, value] : accs) {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   id: 10222, name: 'James Murray', phone_no: '800-222-2222', ss: '333-33-3333', address: '20 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00001', balance: 500
//   id: 10111, name: 'Gerald Gray', phone_no: '800-111-1111', ss: '222-22-2222', address: '19 Driveway Dr, Grayville, CT 00000', balance: 0
```